# NFS client creates file with incorrect permission on the Linux server

Tags: permissions, mount, network-shares, windows-server-2008, nfs

I have a Linux server with a NFS share. User1 and Group1 have `rwx` permissions to the folder. When I create a file on the Linux host as user1, it has the correct permissions. On the Windows machine, I have created the AnonymousUid and AnonymousGid registry entries with the UID and GID of user1 and group1. When I create a file on the Linux NFS share, it assigns `rwxr-x--x` whereas from the Linux host it creates it with `rwxrwx--x`.

How do I correct this issue. I map the NFS share using windows map features and if I go to the mapped drive property, I see the following which is correct:

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Below is what I see on the Linux server:

[image: IMG:]

Gid 30928 is Gid for sapsys

Comment: This has the same problems as your original question at Unix Stack Exchange.  Please provide the required clarification to answer your question per the comments you received there.  You really should have allowed the Unix Stack Exchange community to migrate your question for you instead of cross-posting your question.

Comment: If I create a file on the Linux server where the creator is a member of sapsys, security on the file is rwxrwx--x.
If I connect to the NFS share from another Linux computer and create a file where the user is a member of sapsys then the security is rwxrwx--x.
When I connect to the NFS share from a Windows computer and create a file where user is member of sapsys, security is set to rwx--x--x.  As there will be files created by the Windows machine which needs to be processed on the Linux and moved to a different folder, I require permission rwxrwx--x and this is the issue I need to resolve.